# How can I accurately represent a decimal value to two decimal places in a JSON object in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net-7.0, jsonserializer, asp.net-apicontroller

If I retrieve a value of 1000 from the database, I want to display it as 1000.00. Currently, I am only able to display it as 1000.0, and I don't want to display it as a string format

```
{
    anotherValue: 0.00, 
    value: 1000.0 //no string format "1000.00"
}
```

I use JsonSerializer but it still fails to display 2 decimal digits, it will only be accurate to one decimal place. I am only able to display 2 decimal digits when I set it to 0.00m

```
public class Transaction
{
    public decimal value {get;set;}
    public decimal anotherValue {get;set;} = 0.00m;

}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "display". A JSON number conceptually has no type, but practically speaking is usually interpreted as a floating-point number (even if it's ultimately stored in another type) so expecting a value to be formatted with a specific number of decimal places in JSON, and expecting this to round-trip, is overly optimistic. You may not "want" it to be a string, but as far as preserving precision goes that is the safest way to go about it.

Comment: The question is unclear. Trailing 0s don't matter in numbers. JSON isn't a display format. In  math and programming 1000.0 is equal to 1000.00 and 1000.000000. Teh type `decimal` doesn't have configurable precision either. If you want to *round* the number to a specific precision, eg change `1.2354` to `1.24`, you have to do so in your code or through custom converters.

Comment: Not sure about what you want to do but JSON is a data interchange format and normally you shouldn't worry about the *display format* of the data it contains. Formatting numbers or other data is mostly performed in the presentation (display) layers.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, I have used custom converters, but I can only obtain ```1000.0```since I'm using the ```decimal``` type. How can I show the value as a decimal number instead of a string while maintaining the format 1000.00? I know it's weird to do this kind of formatting....

Comment: If you know it's weird, explain why you want this. You can use [WriteRawValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonwriter.writerawvalue?view=net-7.0) in the converter BUT that requires generating temporary strings. The client's JSON deserializer won't care either, it will deserialize whatever you produce the same way, ignoring trailing 0s

Comment: You can't format numbers. They're numbers. If you want to have .00 you need a string. 
It doesn't matter what you send to whoever is receiving this. When they see : 1000.0, they'll intrepret it as a number, which doesn't have formatting metadata. The number will only be formatted the presentation layer.

This really seems like an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/)